# How to change the color of the Progress Bar in Android?- (I tried one way,and it isn't working)

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar, android-linearlayout, android-drawable

I added a progress bar to my activity using the following code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbHeaderProgress"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ProgressBar>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I call it by:

```
 progressbar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlaHeaderProgress);
 progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The progress bar is displayed and I want to change the color of it. By default the progress bar is displayed in grey color. Here is what I tried to change the color:

I created a xml file in drawables folder and named it as `activityindicator.xml`
The contents of this xml are:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">


        <color android:color="#f58233" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">

        <color android:color="#f58233" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And I changed the layout file as:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/activityindicator"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbHeaderProgress"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/activityindicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ProgressBar>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what I tried, but the color is not changing. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

I am using Lollipop version.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you just want to change the colour, add a colour filter to your progress bar:

```
pbHeaderProgress.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

The Mode parameter, refers to the PorterDuff.Mode Values - available [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html).

Comment: this gives flexibility to choose from colors.xml also   progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(),R.color.product_status_color), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)

Comment: I wanted to use Color.WHITE and this line wasn't working. I had to change porter duff mode to SRC_ATOP

Comment: This method changes color of all progressbars in the app

Comment: For the mode try Mode.SRC_IN if .MULTIPLY doesnt work

Comment: is it possible do change the color in xml?

Answer (score 9):

I just found a way. I don't even need a separate xml file to change the color as the progress bar is of type "indeterminate:true"

I used the following to change the color of my progress bar:

```
pbHeaderProgress.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#C0D000"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

You can get variety of hex color codes from here: http://www.nthelp.com/colorcodes.htm
or 
http://www.color-hex.com/